# Выводится только последний элемент

Tags: python, telegram-bot, requests, telebot, beautiful-soup

Телеграм бот выводит только последние значение (элемент). При том что в консоль выводит все. Я в таком новенький. Дайте совет: что тут не так?

Код:

````
import requests
import telebot
import random
from telebot import types
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs

HEADERS = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://agroplant.com.ua/uk/szr/gerbitsidy/gerbicidi-dlja-soi/', headers = HEADERS)
bot = telebot.TeleBot('5201776897:AAGtPYxcvHk-i-Lsj8sIxB1a8zt3-BEvbTI')
html = Bs(r.text, 'html.parser') 
results = html.find(id="content")
job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="caption")
for job in job_elements:
    name = job.find("div", class_="name")
    price= job.find("div", class_="price")
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, name.text + price.text) 

if __name__ == '__main__':  
 bot.polling(none_stop=True) ```
````

Comment: А где вы пишете print, чтобы в консоль выводить? Если в цикле for, то ничего удивительного. На каждой итерации вы присваиваете этим переменным новые значения и в бот отправятся последние значения

Comment: А как сделать что бы оно давало не последнее значение?

Comment: `import requests`?

Comment: Есть import requests

Answer (score 1):

```py
# pip install tabulate
from tabulate import tabulate
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import re

# Заменил Ваше обращение к странице на открытие файла html сохраненного на диск.
with open('template.html', 'rb') as html_file:
    soup = Soup(html_file.read(), 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id="content")

job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="caption")

rows = []
headers = ['Назва', 'Ціна']

for job in job_elements:
    name = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', a.get_text(strip=True), flags=re.S) if (
        a := name_tg.find_next('a') if (
            name_tg := job.find("div", class_="name")
        ) else None
    ) else None
    price = price_tb.get_text(strip=True) if (
        price_tb := job.find("span", class_="price-normal")
    ) else None

    rows.append(
        (
            name,
            price
        )
    )

data = tabulate(rows, headers=headers, tablefmt="grid")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(data)
```

Вот эту таблицу Вы можете отправить ползователю.
output:

```latex
+---------------------+------------+
| Назва               | Ціна       |
+=====================+============+
| Отаман              | 8 270 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Раундап МАКС        | 8 400 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Ураган Форте 500 SL | 13 840 грн |
+---------------------+------------+
| Харнес              | 11 500 грн |
+---------------------+------------+
| Альфа Бентазон      | 8 810 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Альфа Маїс          | 780 грн    |
+---------------------+------------+
| Багіра Супер        | 1 710 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Базагран            | 3 840 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Гліфовіт            | 7 720 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Грінфорт ІГ 480     | 5 000 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Клінік              | 7 000 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Козак               | 1 700 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Міура               | 3 700 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Норвел              | 3 390 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Норвел Екстра       | 2 380 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Ореол Максі         | 5 150 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Отаман Екстра       | 11 080 грн |
+---------------------+------------+
| Гербіцид Серп       | 2 260 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Торнадо 500         | 2 900 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Тотал               | 4 560 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Тотал К             | 5 230 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Агіл                | 4 870 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Агрітокс            | 2 000 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Адвокат             | 6 710 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Антисапа            | 1 600 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Антисапа Ліквід     | 6 820 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Аценит              | 9 440 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Ацетоган            | 8 030 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Бернар              | 9 090 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Вентура             | 2 770 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Відблок Плюс        | 7 020 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
| Вінес               | 7 340 грн  |
+---------------------+------------+
```